# Is there a way we can club browser detection and media queries in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, media-queries, microsoft-edge

I am trying to write CSS for IE 11 and IE Edge browser detection and browser width media queries both together.

With regular media query for Chrome, I am achieving element width without any issue.

But, if the browser is IE11 and the width is 1360px, then I want to apply red color and the element width should be 800px with green background and if the browser width is 1920px the the element width should be 1200px with red background.

If the browser is Edge and width is 1360px, then I want to apply red color and the element width should be 900px with green background and if the browser width is 1920px the the element width should be 1300px with red background.

And this should not be disturbing my regular classes that are working smoothly for Chrome and Firefox.

Below are the two classes I tried to use to achieve my desired outcome, but which fail to dos o:

**Regular Media Query for Chrome**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .test-class {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
    .test-class {
        width: 80%;
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

**For IE:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .test-class {
        width: 1200px;
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .test-class {
        width: 1200px;
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
    .test-class {
        width: 800px;
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .test-class {
        width: 800px;
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

**For MS Edge**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
        .test-class {
            width: 1200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
    @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
        .test-class {
            width: 800px;
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

When I write the CSS like the above, all the elements are taking 100% for 1920px width browser and 80% width for 1360px browser.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to set the width for the test-class. Here you had posted the sample. So it can possible that in your original code some other CSS affect the output. So you can try to check for it. on my side elements took the width which was set in the CSS.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft Edge is not related to Internet Explorer; it's a totally different web browser. It's not IE Edge, but MS Edge (also not all caps).